# Overlay image on div border top left

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a border of 1 px. I have a square transparent-in-parts png image much smaller than the div 48px * 48px.

I'd like to position the square image such that it overlays the top left border of the div giving the appearance of both top and left borders going underneath the image.

Using background-image 'left top' puts the image inside the div borders which is not what I'm looking for. Wish I could show an example but I don't have any. Hope my question describes it well.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sn22/1/

```
<div id='mybox'>text</div>

#mybox {
text-indent: 0.5in;
background-image:url('http://aerbook.com/site/images/quote-mark-icon-black.png');
border-radius:3px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
height: 300px;
font-weight: 200;
text-indent: 0.35in;
padding: 20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle link with your code.

Comment: provide your source code

Comment: @DS. do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9sn22/2/ read my answer for more info

Comment: Perfect Mr.Alien! Looks so obvious now! Maybe I should go to sleep now! :) Please put this as a separate answer so that I can accept it as an answer and it might help some other sleep-deprived soul some day. Thank you!

Comment: @DS. LOL you welcome :) and btw I've already answered your question, I guess you didn't read my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quiet getting your question as there are no images or any demo for the desired effect you are trying to achieve, but from what I understood, you can use `position: relative;` for the container `div` and use a literal `img` tag inside the `div` and use `position: absolute;` with `top: -1px;` and `left: -1px;` respectively.

If you are trying to make the `background-image` move out of the element area than it's not possible...you need to use `img` for this

```
<div>
   <img src="#" />
</div>

div {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

img {
   position: absolute;
   left: -1px;
   top: -1px;
}
```

Update: (After you added a demo)

Do you need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9sn22/2/)?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q44k5/

html:

```
<div> </div>
```

css:

```
    div{
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px;
    }

div:before{
    content: '';
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css below

```
#cLeft{
    position:absolute;
}
background: #ffffff url('http://spikyarc.net/images/down_Arrow.png') no-repeat top left;
```

try this html below

```
<img id="cLeft" src="http://spikyarc.net/images/down_Arrow.png" />
<div class="content">
  Your Text here.
</div>
```

Comment: This was a solution to a similar question on stackoverflow. But if you look at the JSFiddle, it doesn't work.